# ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run my code for a RNN, but got this error:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'echo_state_rnn_cell/MatMul_3' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [2,1,1000], [1000,1000].

The thing that I don't understand is why my tensor has three dimensions, it should be [1,1000].

My code is:

```
esn_init_state = np.zeros([1, res_size], dtype="float32")
```

`tf.reset_default_graph()
static_graph = tf.Graph()
with static_graph.as_default() as g:`

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(random_seed)
cell = EchoStateRNNCell(num_inputs=input_size, num_units=res_size, decay=0.1, leaky=leak,
                        epsilon=1e-10, alpha=0.0100, rng=rng)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [input_size+res_size, trainlen-initlen])

Yt = data[None, initlen+1:trainlen+1]

init_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, res_size])
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [trainlen,input_size])  #modifica postuma

state = init_state

for t in range(trainlen):
    prev_state = state
    state = cell(inputs=inputs[t:t+1,:], state=prev_state)
    if t >= initlen:
        X[:,t-initlen] = np.vstack((inputs,state))[:,0]
```

The error should be in: `state = cell(inputs=inputs[t:t+1,:], state=prev_state)`.

Here is the definition of cell function:

```
def call(self, inputs, state):
    new_state = (1 - self._leaky*self.decay) * state + self.decay*self._activation(math_ops.matmul(inputs,self.W) + math_ops.matmul(self._activation(state), self.U*self.rho_one))
    output = self._activation(new_state)
    return output, new_state
```

Thanks for your help!